# I can't get the exact method calling for this code

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a simple code in Java but I keep getting error for the method calling.

```
package tutorialproject2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tutorialproject2 {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    InputTest();
    Calculate(); 
    }

    public static void InputTest(){

        String message = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(Hello(message));


    }

    public static String Hello(String message){
       if (message.equals("Hi")){
           return "Hello";
       }else{
           return "Goodbye";
       }  

    }


    public int Calculate(int a,int b){

        a = input.nextInt();
        b = input.nextInt();

        int answer = a * b;

        return answer;

    }
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be in this way,   `int var =  Calculate(3,5);` , can't be `calculate()` alone as it has a return type and arguments.

You could call methods with return type `void` alone like `InputTest();`

as you return `integer` from this method and the method has parameters so you should pass the required parameters here (of integer type),

```
public static int Calculate(int a,int b){
. . .
return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the method `Calculate(int a,int b)` with 2 parameters but call the method without parameters `Calculate()`.
I suppose you should change the method `Calculate(int a,int b)` to

```
public static int Calculate(){

    int a = input.nextInt();
    int b = input.nextInt();

    int answer = a * b;

    return answer;

}
```

and as @Visme mentioned, to add `static` keyword.

or you can leave your method as

```
public int Calculate(){

        int a = input.nextInt();
        int b = input.nextInt();

        int answer = a * b;

        return answer;

}
```

In this case in the `main` function, you should call the method this way:

```
new Tutorialproject2().Calculate();
```

Comment: The error i'm getting says - non-static method Calculate() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: @jay You should add `static` word to the method signature or create instance of your class and then to call method.

Answer (score 2):

Non static method calculate is called from static function (main)